# view datatypes to resolve ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-01790

I'm trying to union three tables, each of which should have the same columns with the same data types:

```
select *
from ALL_1
union all
select *
from ALL_2
union all
select *
from ALL_3
/
```

I keep getting "ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression", so obviously one of the datatypes in one of the tables is different.  Each table should have 40 columns.  I'd like to look at the data types for each column side by side to I can search for discrepancies.  How would I do this?

Comment: The columns might be declared in different order in the original DDL. Why not just write a query that `JOIN`s the tables on a common key and tries to find the differences?

Answer (score 0):

In SQL*Plus, SQL Developer, Toad you can use the SQL*Plus command `DESCRIBE`.

For example:

```
SQL> describe scott.emp

 Name                                              Null?    Type
 ------------------------------------------------- -------- ------------------------
 EMPNO                                             NOT NULL NUMBER(4)
 ENAME                                                      VARCHAR2(10)
 JOB                                                        VARCHAR2(9)
 MGR                                                        NUMBER(4)
 HIREDATE                                                   DATE
 SAL                                                        NUMBER(7,2)
 COMM                                                       NUMBER(7,2)
 DEPTNO                                                     NUMBER(2)
```

Otherwise you can query the catalog tables. This approach is perhaps better because you can write code to do the checking for you (to find exactly where the discrepancies are) rather than you doing it manually.

```
SQL> select column_name, data_type, data_length, data_precision, data_scale
  2  from   all_tab_columns
  3  where  owner = 'SCOTT' and table_name = 'EMP'
  4  order by column_id;

COLUMN_NAME      DATA_TYPE          DATA_LENGTH DATA_PRECISION DATA_SCALE
---------------- ------------------ ----------- -------------- ----------
EMPNO            NUMBER                      22              4          0
ENAME            VARCHAR2                    10
JOB              VARCHAR2                     9
MGR              NUMBER                      22              4          0
HIREDATE         DATE                         7
SAL              NUMBER                      22              7          2
COMM             NUMBER                      22              7          2
DEPTNO           NUMBER                      22              2          0

8 rows selected.
```

For example, you could add `TABLE_NAME` and `COLUMN_ID` to the `SELECT` clause, and change the `WHERE` clause to an `IN (....)` condition; add `order by column_id` and then inspect the output - the columns should appear in groups, first column from all three tables first, then second column from all three tables etc. Or write code to `count(distinct data_type)`, `group by column_id`, and see which groups have a count of more than 1.